# How do I go about creating this SQL query?

Tags: query

I'm attending the free DB course at Stanford Online, and frankly one of the  exercises gave me some trouble. I have a feeling that this should be horribly simple, so for a DBA, I'm obviously not very good with SQL.

We're working with a simplified scenario for rating movies.

> For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.

Here's the schema:

```
Movie ( mID, title, year, director ) 
Reviewer ( rID, name ) 
Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: Rated the movie exactly twice and no more?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can self join to tables for this sort of criteria(at least, I can do this in SQL Server):

```
SELECT
     r.name,
     m.title
FROM
    rating rt
    JOIN movie m ON (rt.mid = m.mid)
    JOIN reviewer r on (rt.rid = r.rid)
    JOIN rating rt2 on (rt.mid = rt2.mid and rt.rid = rt2.rid)
WHERE
    rt.ratingDate > rt2.ratingDate
    AND rt.stars >  rt2.stars;
```

Note that we're joing rating back to itself.  This way we can use the WHERE clause to find rows in `rating` that are greater in both date and stars to other rows in `rating`.

You can review the full example I built in SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df62f/3).

---

If you want to add the condition that the reviewer made exactly these 2 reviews of the movie and no more, you can add:

```
    AND NOT EXISTS                                  --- not exists
        ( SELECT *
          FROM rating rt3                           --- another rating
          WHERE rt3.mid = m.mid                     --- for same movie
            AND rt3.rid = r.rid                     --- by same reviewer
            AND rt3.ratingDate <> rt2.ratingDate    --- on different date
            AND rt3.ratingDate <> rt1.ratingDate    --- than the first 2 reviews
        )
```

This assumes that the `Rating` table has  `(rID, mID, ratingDate)` as primary key.

Comment: The only issue I see with the first query is that if there are `n` reviews for a movie (by the same reviewer) and all have ascending (per date) ratings, the `(movie,reviewer)` combination will be shown `n*(n-1)/2` times. Of course this can be taken care with `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an analytic solution using the tables miracle173 built in SQL Fiddle.  The analytics alleviate the need to query the Ratings table <strike>two</strike> three times.

```
SELECT re.Name, mo.Title FROM
(
   SELECT rID, mID, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rID, mID) MovieCount, stars
      , Lag(Stars) OVER (PARTITION BY rID, mID ORDER BY ratingDate) LagStars
   FROM Rating
) ra
JOIN Movie mo ON mo.mID = ra.mID
JOIN Reviewer re ON re.rID = ra.rID
WHERE MovieCount = 2 AND Stars > LagStars;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6957e/16

Answer (score 3):

```
select name,title
from Rating Rating1 join Rating Rating2 on( 
Rating1.mID=Rating2.mID 
and Rating1.rID=Rating2.rID
and Rating1.ratingDate Rating1.stars)
join Movie on (Movie.mID=Rating1.mID)
join Reviewer on (Reviewer.rID=Rating1.rID)
and (Rating1.rID, Rating1.mID) in (select rID,mID
from Rating
group by rID,mID
having count(*)=2)
;
```

You can check it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6957e/7.

It will only consider the films of a reviewer that he has rated exactly two times

Answer (score 3):

A solution that combines parts from the previous answers is the following:

```
select
  name,title
from 
  rating rt1
  join rating rt2 on (rt1.rID = rt2.rID and rt1.mID = rt2.mID)
  join reviewer on (rt1.rID = reviewer.rID)
  join movie on (rt1.mID = movie.mID)
where
  rt1.ratingdate < rt2.ratingdate 
  and rt1.stars < rt2.stars
  and rt1.rID in (
    select rID
    from Rating r1
    group by r1.rID,r1.mID
    having count(*)=2);
```